# How to find maximum value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Say in table A, we have application name and location where those applications are used.

I'm looking to find the location where an application is being used the most. In case of ties, both locations should be returned.

Table content:

```
Application Location
A            xy
A            xy
A            ab
B            xy
B            ab
B            ab
```

Expected output:

```
Application   Max(Loc)
A             xy
B             ab
```

Comment: What if there is a tie?

Comment: return both the locations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be solved using the aggregation function [`RANK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/ms176102.aspx). Use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/ms186734.aspx) instead to return only one row per application in case of ties.

Example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e38c4).

```
SELECT application, location
FROM (
  SELECT application, location,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY application ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rn
  FROM t
  GROUP BY application, location
) x
WHERE rn = 1;
```